# send HTML from servlet to JSP dynamically

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, dynamic

Is there an easy way to send HTML from a servlet to a JSP, using AJAX.

I've already figured out how to make AJAX work with servlets dynamically, but now I want to press a button on a form and generate HTML based on text-input.

Is it possible, and if so, how, to send just pieces of HTML to an existing HTML page?

Example,

I have a basic form where you can input your age, and based on the age the text has a different size/color. So, you send for example, 25 as your age to the servlet, and it send back a piece of HTML like this `<p STYLE="font-size: age;">` to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through ajax call you can get the output result either a string, html or a Json object that will be parsed and results can be displayed over JSP/HTML. So for sure you can send html code segment from servlet to jsp through ajax call.

For example you can use this approach--

```
 1. Take a string variable in your servlet.
 2. Put appropriate html string as per your conditions in this string variable
 3. send this string as a response from servlet like:

response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

response.getWriter().write("your string variable here"); 

 4. In your ajax call do like this:

    success : function(dataString) {
                document.getElementById("containerId").innerHTML=dataString;
    },
```

where containerId is the id of html element (like div or span) where you want to display output html.

Comment: In my case the code looks like this :
http://pastebin.com/Zde3T10Q
I just added the innerHTML to test, but it didn't work, I think I should approach it differently in my case, but I do not know how

Comment: Did you try to keep an alert in your function whether you are getting value in responseText?

Comment: I am getting values back from the servlet, I have tried returning just plain text and display it, and that works for me, but I can't do anything with innerHTML, I might be doing something wrong though

Comment: What value you are sending from servlet as html ? Can you post your servlet code along with jsp?

Comment: JSP : http://pastebin.com/X5QVdfaf
Servlet : http://pastebin.com/KDtMjVQf

I already did some tweaking to see if I could figure it out, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: use document.getElementById... You are using document.getElementId("textArea").innerHTML = responseText; By is missing there in your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach, without client-side javascript libraries, would be to point an HTML form to an iframe, just like

```
<iframe name="myIframe"...>

<form target="myIframe"...>
```

And submit your form as many times as necessary.  The HTML returned by the servlet would load itself in the iframe element.

If you like AJAX and client-side javascript libraries, you can find very easy programmatical ways to do this in jQuery and similar libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your servlet can generate any kind of content, e.g. JSON, HTML etc.
You'd then send that content back to the client and integrate it into the page.
How that is done depends on the type of content.

Example:

You issue an AJX request (e.g. by using jQuery's ajax functionality) and your servlet generates plain html. When your JavaScript receives the anser you just replace the relevant part, e.g. by replacing the content of some defined element.

If you used JSON instead, your servlet might send data only instead, e.g. a font size based on the age as in your example. You'd then use JavaScript to access that JSON data and perform relevant operations, e.g. by changing the style of the paragraph.